# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax. Is TIME data type not supported in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, import

I'v been trying to import my db and keeps giving me this error.

Table:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `doc_info` (

`dname` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`dcontact` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`reg_num` INT( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`specialization` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`experience` VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
`category` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`availablefrom` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`password` VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL ,
`username` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`availableto` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`gender` VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
`email` TEXT NOT NULL ,
`pincode` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
`address` VARCHAR( 200 ) NOT NULL ,
`wcontact` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
`timeto` TIME( 4 ) NOT NULL ,
`timefrom` TIME( 4 ) NOT NULL ,
`latitude` FLOAT( 10, 6 ) NOT NULL ,
`longitude` FLOAT( 10, 6 ) NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
```

Error:- Is Time data type not supported in mysql cause its highlighted in RED in the MySQL Documentation.. How do i fix this error?

```
 MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(4) NOT    NULL,
 `timefrom` time(4) NOT NULL,
 `latitude` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
' at line 17
```

Comment: what version are you on  ... `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";`

Comment: I am on  version 4.3.11
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1Server version: 5.6.24
-- PHP Version: 5.6.8

Comment: ok you did an edit to your comment. I assume it is a phpmyadmin issue because 5.6.24 should support that. I am on 5.6.24 and your create worked fine. Which come to think of it, why would phpmyadmin get involved with a 1064 ... rather just report back to you.

Comment: So, ditch the `(4)` in the 2 places

Comment: thank you so muc.. that did the job..